# What is the accepted or acknowledge way to turn to professor or teacher?

Tags: word-request, forms-of-address

What is the accepted or acknowledge way to turn to professor or teacher at the college or at the university?

For example if I have a question to ask him, Should I say to him "professor" or "teacher" or there is another way to do it? I have African friends who say to the teacher (female) "mom", while Indian friends say to the teacher (male) "Sir". so I am confused in this topic and I'd like to know one time what is the way to turn to teachers in USA, England, Australia, South Africa and Canada.

Comment: It's probably not possible to answer this question as it is to culturally variable depending on location and other factors.

Comment: Is there no one way that I can use it in any anglo-saxon country?

Comment: I think J.R.'s answer explains the variability sufficiently well to explain what can be used in different contexts, and the problem of cultural differences.

Comment: Note, by the way, that in the US *ma'am* is pronounced with /æ/ (as in *ham*), not /ɑ/ (as in *mom*).

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., *teachers* generally teach at the K-12 levels, while *professors* teach at colleges and universities.

It's also quite unusual in the U.S. to refer to a teacher as "Teacher," except perhaps at the elementary level. In the middle school and high school environments, teachers are usually known by their last name, with a prefix (for example: *Mr. Jones, Mrs. Smith, Ms. Davis,* or *Miss Miller*).

At the collegiate level, it's less uncommon for professors to be known as "Professor." Assuming the professor holds a doctorate degree, though, many of them prefer to be referred to as *Doctor* (for example, *Dr. Brown*).

However, these very general guidelines can vary quite a bit: not just from country to country or school to school, but even from department to department. My daughter goes to a university where, in her department (which happens to be the Theater department), most of the professors prefer to be called by their first name (*Dave* or *Nichole*, for example). However, I believe other departments are not quite so informal with their students. It might vary by generation, too. Ultimately, though, it's a personal preference.

If you are worried about not being respectful enough, you can use *Sir* or *Ma'am* initially – that's usually pretty safe. The only way to know for sure, though, is to simply ask:

> What would you prefer that I call you?

or:

> How do want me to address you?

You could change the first person pronouns to a more collective question, if you'd like:

> How do you prefer that your students you? Professor? Doctor?

I think you'll find that most professors will be happy to answer that question, and get the awkwardness and doubt out of the way.